Conditions of strong convexity for non-smooth functions
I was reading this paper for some results on the strong convexity for non-smooth functions but I'm not getting this proposition at all:
Lema II
(i) $f$ is strongly convex with parameter $\mu$.
(ii)    $f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha) y) \leq \alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha) f(y) - \frac{\mu}{2} \alpha (1-\alpha) \| y - x \|^2$ for any $x, y$.
(iii) $f(y) \geq f(x) + s_x^T (y-x) + \frac{\mu}{2} \| y - x \|^2$ for all $x, y$ and any $s_x \in \partial f(x)$.
(iv) $(s_y - s_x)^T (y - x) \geq \mu \| y - x \|^2$ for all $x, y$ and any $s_x \in \partial f(x)$, $s_y \in \partial f(y)$.
Proof
(i) $\iff$ (ii) It follows from the definition of convexity for $g(x) = f(x) - \frac{\mu}{2} x^T x$.
(i) $\iff$ (iii) It follows from the equivalent first-order condition of convexity for $g$.
(i) $\iff$ (iv) It follows from the equivalent monotonicity of (sub)-gradient of convexity for $g$.
The fact that in some cases it is necessary to compute the subgradient of $g(x) = f(x) - \frac{\mu}{2}||x||^2$ blows my mind since the subgradient of $-||x||^2$ does not exist since it is concave.
Is it still possible to compute the subgradient of it as its gradient assuming that $g(x)$ is convex?

Since $g$ is convex we get $$f =g+(\mu/2)||x||^2\implies \partial f = \partial g + \partial (\mu/2)||x||^2$$
